# How To Set the Animated Images As UILabel Background?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uilabel

I try to Set the Animated Images as UILabel Background. my label move from point (x=0 y260 to x=480 y=260) i want to add UIImage during animation. So for i try like this

```
UIImageView *myimg=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        myimg.animationImages =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"1ANI.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2ANI.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"3ANI.png"],nil];

        myimg.animationDuration = 1.5;
        myimg.animationRepeatCount = 0;
        [myimg startAnimating]; 
        [lbl1 addSubview:myimg];
        [myimg release];
```

I Set the UILabel Background with a Single UIImage Like this

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1ANI.png"];
            lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Single Image Code works,but when i try to Implement it with Animates images(as above my Code show)  then its not works Can some one guide me how to to set animated images as a UILabel Background.Thanx

Comment: You're stuck putting the imageView behind a label with a clear background.  If you're worried about wanting your animation to move around with the label put them both in another UIView and move that around instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 21)];
[label setText:@"asfsdf" ];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIImageView *imagView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 21)];
imagView.animationImages =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1ANI.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2ANI.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3ANI.png"],nil];

imagView.animationDuration = 1.5;
imagView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imagView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imagView];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: the label has no transparent background.. you have to make it transparent with `lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Can it possible to add imageview to uilabel.beacuse my UILabel move along the screen so its not suit me to create imageview at specific point thats why i need to add uiimageview at my UILabel.

Comment: Hmm it may be hard to include image in 'UILabel'.OK you can do one thing,create a subclass of UIView and add both the imageview and UILabel as mentioned above and use it directly for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

First of all   do not add the UIImageView to label as subview with `[lbl1 addSubview:myimg];`

Add the imageview first and than add the uilabel on to it.Your label will be transparent and float on the uiimageview.

you might also need to  `[imageView setuserinteractionEnabled:YES];` for the uiimageview.

Comment: the label has no transparent background.. you have to make it transparent with `lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Can it possible to add imageview to uilabel.beacuse my UILabel move along the screen so its not suit me to create imageview at specific point thats why i need to add uiimageview at my UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

This work in iOS 7

[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panel_dev_header"]]];